# Android BottomSheet Initial Behaviour

Tags: android, material-design

So I want to implement a Bottom Sheet behavior and everything works fine except at first (when activity is created) the bottom sheet is not positioned how I configured it.
I can't find any information on why this is happening or if it is some configuration I am missing.

I prepared a sample code and some images to show the problem:

**The activity** (I haven't done anything, this is the initial template)

```
package com.example.testbottomsheet;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**The Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.flavio.testbottomsheet.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/transaction_history"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:behavior_hideable="false"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="40dp"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bottomSheetHandler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:contentDescription="Handles for bottom sheet"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_expand_less_24dp" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#156de8"></FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

As one can see I have a **peekHeight** of **40dp**, and it works fine after I expand and close it )or just a small flick on top of the bottom sheet), however it is not initially set like this. I colored everything to be easier to spot:

**Open Pane**
[image: Open Pane]

**Should-be initial state**
[image: Should-be initial state]

**IS initial state**
[image: IS initial state]

From what I could see the bottom sheet is being placed 20dp bellow of the desired number configured in the XML.

Answer (score 1):

Its a bug in design support lib.. take a look at this link:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=203057

Comment: Hey thanks for the Tipp.  It seems exactly my problem but even after changing to the version 23.2.1 my problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to the LinearLayout that you have added the BottomSheetBehaviour to.